# Client/Server in Python

Tags: python, server, tcp, client

I tried to implement a communication between server and client in python. I need to send a message between them, bidirectional , but I don't know how to make it as a continuous communication, because in my programm connection is closed after server and client sent only a message. Can anybody help me?

This is my code for server :

```
import socket

serv = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

serv.bind(('0.0.0.0', 8082))
serv.listen(5)

while True:
    conn, addr = serv.accept()
    from_client=''
    while True:
        from_client=''
        data = conn.recv(4096)
        if not data : break
        from_client+=data
        print from_client
    
        print("Send character to CLIENT ")
        input1=str(raw_input())
        conn.send(input1)
    
        print("You received from client the next Character")
        from_client=''
        data = conn.recv(4096)
        if not data : break
        from_client+=data
        print from_client
        print'\n'
   conn.close()
   print 'client disconenct'
```

This is my code for client :

```
import socket

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(('0.0.0.0', 8082))

client.send("I am CLIENT\n")
from_server = client.recv(4096)
print("I received from SERVER %s" %from_server)
print("Send your character to SERVER")
input1=str(raw_input())
client.send(input1)

client.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your connection closed because `client.close()`

If your client behaves just like the server to repeat to request you send some message to the server and then receives what the server send, you can create a Ping-Pong application that one side repeats input-send-receive cycle while the other repeats receive-input-send cycle.